# Type of a certain class

Tags: c#, design-patterns

I am wondering whether there is way to limit the Type variable to a certain class only. For example

```
    public class Product
    {
       public string Name;
       public bool Install;

       public List<Type> Components;
       public List<Type> Prerequisite;
    }
```

If the List can be specified to be of typeof(Product) and its derivatives, I think it will make my generic design much more straightforward and easy to use. Maybe like so:

```
    public class Product
    {
       public string Name;
       public bool Install;

       public List<Type<Product>> Components;
       public List<Type<Product>> Prerequisite;
    }
```

Do you know of a method to do so? Thank you for your thoughts.

Comment: `List<Product>`, I'm not sure  you understand generics or specifying the type properties... Or are you really wanting to store Type references and not instances of a type?

Comment: It's really not clear what you're trying to accomplish with `List< Type<Product> >`.  What is `Type<Product>`?  Why won't `List<Product>` just work?

Comment: Hi Ron Beyer, yes, I want to store the type references and not the instances.

Answer (score 3):

Now, your question seems strange to me. Are you sure you don't have a list of `Product`s as components instead of `Type`s? Regardless, here's a way to do it:

```
class Wheel : Product { }
class Engine : Product { }

class Product {
     List<Type> components;

     public IReadOnlyCollection<Type> Components { get { return components } }

     void AddComponent<T>() where T : Product 
     {
         components.Add(typeof(T));
     }   
 }

 var car = new Product();
 car.AddComponent<Engine>();
 car.AddComponent<Wheel>();
```

So basically you can register a type known to the caller at compile time and add it to the list of types. This does not allow adding other types since the `Components` property is read only and does not allow modifying the resulting collection.

---

Are you sure you don't want a `Product`'s `Components` to be products as well?

In that case you can use standard [polymorphism](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Polymorphism_%28computer_science%29#Subtyping) (specifically, [subtype polymorphism](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Subtyping)):

```
 Product car = new Product();
 car.Components.Add(new Engine());
 car.Components.Add(new Wheel());
 car.Components.Add(new Wheel());
 car.Components.Add(new Wheel());
 car.Components.Add(new Wheel());
```

Comment: I was in the process of typing up almost exactly the same thing. Only thing you need to do is actually create the list instance (null reference right now) and add a ; in the return for the property.

Comment: AHA!!!! That's it!!! Thank you Bas. You made this looks so easy. Yes I want it to only be a type reference and not the instance. What you have shown in the first code block is perfect. Thanks you!